# Spring Boot Controller not mapping (Whitelabel Error Page 404)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've tried it on IntelliJ and STS 4 but i'm getting the same whitelabel error, except when i put the @restcontroller inside the main application, so i think the problem is in the package structure. I've tried a lot of things (with and without component scan, on the same and on a subpackage, with both IDE's)  yet none worked :( Spring 3.0.3. Im accessing http://localhost:8080/hello

[image]

IFredApplication.java (main)

```
package com.ifred.app;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.ifred.app"})

public class IfredApplication {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(IfredApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

hello.java(controller)

```
package com.ifred.app.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class hello {
    
    @GetMapping
    public String hi() {
        return"Hello world";
    }

}
```

And this is my POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.ifred</groupId>
    <artifactId>ifred</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ifred</name>
    <description>projeto ifood</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Console Output

```
[2m2023-02-26T10:43:59.509-03:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5492[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.ifred.app.IfredApplication          [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting IfredApplication using Java 17.0.6 with PID 5492 (D:\Frederico\Softwares\Projetos Spring Tools Suite\ifred\target\classes started by Pichau in D:\Frederico\Softwares\Projetos Spring Tools Suite\ifred)
[2m2023-02-26T10:43:59.513-03:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5492[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.ifred.app.IfredApplication          [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
[2m2023-02-26T10:44:00.280-03:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5492[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
[2m2023-02-26T10:44:00.290-03:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5492[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting service [Tomcat]
[2m2023-02-26T10:44:00.291-03:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5492[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.5]
[2m2023-02-26T10:44:00.391-03:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5492[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
[2m2023-02-26T10:44:00.391-03:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5492[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mw.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 830 ms
[2m2023-02-26T10:44:00.710-03:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5492[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
[2m2023-02-26T10:44:00.721-03:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5492[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.ifred.app.IfredApplication          [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Started IfredApplication in 1.597 seconds (process running for 2.4)
[2m2023-02-26T10:44:09.601-03:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5492[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
[2m2023-02-26T10:44:09.602-03:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5492[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
[2m2023-02-26T10:44:09.602-03:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5492[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Completed initialization in 0 ms
```

Tried using IntelliJ and STS4, tried changing the package structure, putting on the same package and on a subpackage, tried using only @controller with and without response body, tried only request mapping, tried only get mapping, tried using component scan with (basePackages={"com.ifred.app"}) and (basePackages={"com.ifred.controller"}), tried different browser. It only worked once when i called the @restcontroller inside the IfredApplication class, but will cause problems in the future.

EDIT 1: So apparently the problem is on the first time i start the file, something on the project structure, still trying to figure it out. When i send the project files to my friend's pc it wont work, but if he creates the project (the exact same way i did with spring initializr) and runs it for the first time on his PC, it works on every pc. If he send the file for me to run for the first time on my PC it works on neither.

Comment: What is the full url you’re using to make the request?

Comment: Did you by chance override the default context path? If so, try changing it to `‘/‘` instead of `‘’`

Comment: no luck still got whitelabel error :(

Answer (score -1):

Please remove `@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.ifred.app"})` as it is of no use since you are using `@SpringBootApplication`.

[@SpringBootApplication](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html) already comprised of @ComponentScan

Comment: It’s of no use or is actively causing issues? If they latter, how is it causing the issues described in the question?

Answer (score -2):

instead of the @RequestMapping having /hello use /api and then use @GetMapping("/hello")

ex:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello, World!";
    }
}
```

client sends a GET request to /api/hello, the hello() method will be executed and return the string "Hello, World!".

Comment: still did not work :( i guess the problem is not on the code but on my IDE/project settings.. Thank you for the response!

Comment: I see you are using intelliJ, I'm an eclipse guy. IDEs do have odd issues and configs. If you stay stuck maybe try creating a maven project in eclipse and try there. (note, some intelliJ imports to eclipse can be weird. if not far along just rewrite in eclipse or copy paste). If eclipse runs, then you dont have to battle both maybes and have direction. lmk if so ill help

Comment: Hey Mason, thank you for the help :) As it turns out i just had a space in my folder's name, causing this issue.